# GCC -v returns GCC 4.7.3 even though I unpacked 4.8.1?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, mingw

so I went to this link [Source Forge MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/32-bit/threads-win32/sjlj/) to download and install MinGW 4.8.1. (rev 5).  I unpack it into C:\MinGW\mingw32.   So I open command prompt (win 32 system) and run gcc -v and I get GCC is 4.7.3.  This is the full output of gcc -v:

```
C:\MinGW\mingw32>gcc -v Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin Configured with:
/cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/src/gcc-4.7.3
/configure
--srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/src/gcc-4.
7.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --lib execdir=/usr/lib --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --d atarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --ho st=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix
--without-li bintl-prefix --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-ver sion-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwar f2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-langu ages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads= posix --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmat h-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-subli bs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers
--with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar -
-with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-ppl --with-sy stem-zlib : (reconfigured) /cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/src
/gcc-4.7.3/configure
--srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/ src/gcc-4.7.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin
--sbindir=/usr/ sbin --libexecdir=/usr/lib --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdi r=/etc --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc -C --build=i686-pc-c ygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix -- without-libintl-prefix --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static -- enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap
--disable-__cxa_atexit -
-with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --en able-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++
--enable-graphite --enabl e-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable- libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-li bgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers
--with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java /ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-ppl  --with-system-zlib Thread model: posix gcc version 4.7.3 (GCC)

C:\MinGW\mingw32>
```

I would like to know why it unpacked an earlier version and how to fix this. Apparently C::B see's it as an earlier build too! It really baffles me O.o
Also, the prompt returns that threads use Posix when it should be Win32, again really rattling my brain here.

If any one can point to some links, or clear any of this up it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you unpacked, and what the OS presents when you call the program, need not be the same thing. Did you do a rehash? Confirm that the path is the same? Or is the new version at a later point in the path? You might want to alias the `gcc` command to the version you want. Type `which gcc` to see where the OS thinks the "current version" is located - that should help. **EDIT** I realize the `which` command may not work in windows (just noticed the `C:` drive letter) but the main point about paths is still valid.

Comment: Brilliant! Before I installed Msys I would have to travel to the location where I installed/unpacked gcc to run gcc -v. AFter installing Msys and taking your advice with "which gcc" I found the location is point to /usr/bin/gcc.  Ok so somthing else must be keeping my program from compiling properly... Other than that thakns for your help, I'd say this is solved!   Er... How do I check this off as solved? Long time listener here at SOF first time caller :P

Comment: I have re-posted my comment as an "answer" so you can mark it as "solved"... using the little check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @allegory: It is SO. Just SO. SOF is "Soldier of Fortune".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you unpacked, and what the OS presents when you call the program, need not be the same thing. Did you do a rehash? Confirm that the path is the same? Or is the new version at a later point in the path? You might want to alias the gcc command to the version you want. Type which gcc to see where the OS thinks the "current version" is located - that should help. EDIT I realize the which command may not work in windows (just noticed the C: drive letter) but the main point about paths is still valid.

Comment: After editing the path I can, as I usually did and as I am accustomed to, cd to the directory containing gcc.exe and run gcc -v returning the correct version 8.4.1 :D